# In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same

Tags: image, matlab, location, variable-assignment, pixel

Can you please help me to correct the above mentioned problem in the following matlab code ?

```
    E = [5,200];  Selected edge values 
    X = imread('LENNA128.bmp');
    N = length(X);
    Y = false(N+2);
for k = 1:numel(E);
    Y(2:end-1,2:end-1) = X==E(k);
    Z = Y(1:end-2,2:end-1) | Y(3:end,2:end-1) | Y(2:end-1,3:end) | Y(2:end-1,1:end-2);
    X(Z) = round((X(end-3,3:end-2) + X(end-3,4:end-1))/2);
end
```

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve with that code? Why the `Y = false(N+2)`?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I am trying to get rid of that error.

Comment: Yes I know that. But sometimes it's good to understand the purpose of a code don't you think?

Comment: Which line throws the error?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html Use the debugging tools.

Answer (score -1):

i guess thats matlab code (maybe add matlab tag next time). if you look at the colon operator in matlab doc http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html then when used on left side of an assignement it will fill the matrix and keep dimenesions so you need same amount of elements.